# How can I make my HTML form turn a positive number into a negative one?

Tags: javascript, html

I currently have the following HTML form;

```html
<form method = "POST" action = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxjxbUoJes8WFs1ybMpsnYbaiJcFI1PkVFf0y0avSdKmsxtys7LKi6Zdr7tmWyw/exec" id = "groceryExpenses" style = "display:none" onsubmit='addExpense(); checkIfExpense();'>
 <div class="row">
  <div>
    <label>Car Name</label>
      <input  name = "Car" id = 'carName' style = "width: 24%;" type="text" placeholder="Enter the car name" id="exampleEmailInput">
     </div>
    </div>
      <div>
         <div>
       <label style = 'padding-bottom: 1pt;' for="exampleEmailInput">Gas Station</label>
         <input name = "Gas Station" id="gasStation" style = "width: 24%;" type="text" placeholder="Enter the gas station" id="exampleEmailInput">
     </div>
                              
  <label>Amount</label>
  <input name = "Amount" id="amount" style = "width: 24%;" type="number" placeholder="Enter amount spent" id="exampleEmailInput">
   </div>
                            
                    
<button type = 'submit' class="button-primary">Add expense</button>
<button type = 'button' class="button-primary" onclick="closeExpenseForm()">Close Form</button>

                    
   </form>
```

Upon submission, I would like to check if the inputs of `gasStation` and `carName` are not empty. If there are not, then `amount` will be turned to a negative number. I have tried the following;

```js
function checkIfExpense(){
    if (document.getElementById('gasStation').value.length !==0 && document.getElementById('carName').value.length !==0){
        amount = Math.abs(amount)*-1; //I have instantiated this variable earlier in my JS file.
    }
}
```

However, it does not seem to be working. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You've given multiple ids to some elements and also used the same id for multiple elements. Ids should be unique within the document, and elements should have only a single id.

Answer (score 0):

set that negative amount using:

```
document.getElementById('amount').value = amount
```

Try This:

```js
function checkIfExpense(e) {
    const gasStation = document.getElementById('gasStation').value;
    const carName = document.getElementById('carName').value;
    let amount = document.getElementById('amount').value;
    if (!gasStation || !carName || gasStation == null || carName == null || gasStation == '' || carName == ''){
        amount = amount ? Math.abs(amount)*-1 : 0;
        console.log(amount);
        document.getElementById('amount').value = amount;
    }
}
```

```html
<div>
    <label>Car Name</label>
    <input  name="Car" id='carName' style="width: 24%;" type="text" placeholder="Enter the car name" id="exampleEmailInput">
</div>
<div>
    <label style = 'padding-bottom: 1pt;' for="exampleEmailInput">Gas Station</label>
    <input name="Gas Station" id="gasStation" style = "width: 24%;" type="text" placeholder="Enter the gas station" id="exampleEmailInput">
</div>
     
<div>
    <label>Amount</label>
    <input name="Amount" id="amount" style="width: 24%;" type="number" placeholder="Enter amount spent" id="exampleEmailInput">
</div>
                                                
<button type='submit' onclick="checkIfExpense()" class="button-primary">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, what you are trying to achieve. But you can also do this...

```
  function checkIfExpense(){
  if (document.getElementById('gasStation').value.length !==0 && document.getElementById('carName').value.length !==0){
      var amount = document.getElementById('amount');
        amount = amount.value;
    alert(-amount);
```

}
}